# How to read multiple values from a column of a .csv file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, sh

this is sample csv file :

```
name,annotations,description
drgreghouse,princeton,"doctor,head"
sheldon,tbbt,"physicist,actor"
chandler,friends,"actor,comedian"
```

I am trying something like this but it is reading only first values

```
INPUT="$(pwd)/data.csv"
IFS=','
sed 1d $INPUT |while read name annotations description; do
    echo "$name $annotations $description"
done
```

O/p -

```
drgreghouse princeton "doctor
sheldon tbbt "physicist
chandler friends "actor
```

Expected O/p

```
drgreghouse princeton doctor,head
sheldon tbbt physicist,actor
chandler friends actor,comedian
```

Comment: @anubhava I have updated the expected o/p

Comment: You can get your output using `tail -n +2 file`

Comment: @Kunalkishor, or do you want to skip only headers in Input_file and keep rest of the lines in your file?

Comment: @anubhava That is no real improvement over `sed 1d` though.

Comment: `IFS` means input field separator. This is the character which gets used by `read` to distinguish the columns.

Comment: @Kunalkishor: Try: `awk -F'\t' 'NR>1{print $1, $2}' file`

Comment: @anubhave You'll want to add `OFS='\t'` to that too.

Comment: @tripleee: I didn't see OP mentioning tab in output. Anyway if that's needed then `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}` is considered better way.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` and the shell have no concept of CSV files. If you want to process quoted fields in CSV, you have to handle the quoted fields yourself, or switch to a tool which handles them for you.

If your data has no complex quoting, you can replace every non-quoted comma with a different delimiter which doesn't occur in the data (try `|` maybe) and take it from there. If you just want to convert to space-delimited, try this.

```sh
sed -e 1d -e 's/"\([^"]*\)",\|\([^[",]*\),/\1\2 /g' data.csv
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/sg9crO

To use a different delimiter, change the space after `\1\2` to that delimiter. But again, please understand that this quick and dirty regex hack cannot handle the full range of CSV's quoting rules.

As an aside, you don't need `$(pwd)` to refer to the current directory; relative file names are always resolved relative to your current working directory already.